# PHP foreach returning last row in multidimentional array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying get user value from multidimensional array as

```
$array = array();

$array["id"] = "1";
$array["name"] = "name1";
$array["country"] = "country1";

$array["id"] = "2";
$array["name"] = "name2";
$array["country"] = "country2";

$array["id"] = "3";
$array["name"] = "name3";
$array["country"] = "country3";

$array["id"] = "4";
$array["name"] = "name4";
$array["country"] = "country4";

foreach($array as $e){
    print_r($e);
}
```

It return me `4name4country4` only

I need to fetch rows like

```
foreach($array as $e){
    $id=$e['id'];
    $name=$e['name'];
    $country=$e['country'];
    echo $id.'/'.$name.'/'.$country.'<br>';
}
```

but this gives me error as `Illegal string offset 'id'`
from what I understood about array this should return all values, Please see why this simple array is not working and suggest any way to do it

Comment: You are overwriting the `key`s.

Comment: @b0s3, Is there a way to mass multiple keys.

Comment: you could do it like this `$temp_array["id"] = "1";$temp_array["name"] = "name1";$temp_array["country"] = "country1";` and do `array_push($array, $temp_array)`, you should do this for each set of array

Comment: your array contains only last element.please check print_r($array);

Comment: @TallboY please see my answer ... in my answer, you will not have to specify array keys manually ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you are overwriting the `key`s. Need to add the `key`s properly. You have to build the array like -

```
$array[0]["id"] = "1";
$array[0]["name"] = "name1";
$array[0]["country"] = "country1";

$array[1]["id"] = "2";
$array[1]["name"] = "name2";
$array[1]["country"] = "country2";
```

OR

```
$array = array(
   0 => array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'name1', 'country' => 'country1'),
   1 => array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'name2', 'country' => 'country2'),
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead, do it like so you won't have to give array keys manually

```
$array = array();

$array[] = array("id" => 123,  "name" => "Your name",  "country" =>  "UK");
$array[] = array("id" => 1342,  "name" => "Your name 2 ",  "country" =>  "UK");
```

then in `foreach` do this

```
foreach($array as $key => $val){

echo $key. ":     ".$val['id']. " " . $val['name'];
}
```

Comment: This solution is also good but in my application I have to change values which would be easier if array has a key to it. thanks

Comment: @TallboY look at my edited answer, please see foreach loop, it has a $key`` variable which will have the key of `$array` values being iterated

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the multidimensional array like this, right now you're overwriting the array multiple times.

```
$arrays = [
  [0]=>
    ["id"] => "1",
    ["name"] => "name1",
    ["country"] => "country1"
  ], 
  [1]=>[
     ...
  ]
];
foreach($arrays as $array){
    $id=$array['id'];
    $name=$array['name'];
    $country=$array['country'];
    echo $id.'/'.$name.'/'.'$country'.'<br>';
}
```